# What are the obstacles for Scala having "const classes" a la Fantom?

Tags: scala

Fantom supports [provably immutable](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Classes.html#const) classes. The advantages of the compiler knowing a class is immutable must be numerous, not the least of which would be guaranteed immutable messages passed between actors. Fantom's approach seems straightforward - what difficulties would it pose for Scala?

Comment: Don't see much difference between these `const classes` and simple `case class Whatever(..)`, except for `A non-const class cannot inherit from a const class`.

Comment: case classes are just vals (non-reassignable) - they're only immutable if all of their fields are also immutable (and so on)

Comment: and this is the common way to use case classes, as immutable data holders, no?

Comment: case classes throughout the entire hierarchy is common, but the compiler can't exploit that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's more interest on Scala side on tracking side effects, which is a much harder proposition, than simply immutability.

Immutability in itself isn't as relevant as referential transparency, and, as a matter of fact, some of Scala's immutable collections would not pass muster on an "proven immutable" test because, in fact, they are not. They are immutable *as far as anyone can observer* from the outside, but they have mutable fields for various purposes.

One such example is `List`'s subclass `::` (the class that makes up everything in a list but the empty list), in which the fields for `head` and `tail` are actually mutable. This is done that way so that a `List` can be composed efficiently in FIFO order -- see `ListBuffer` and its `toList` method.

Regardless, while it would be interesting to have a guarantee of immutability, such things are really more of a artifact of languages where mutability is the default. It doesn't come up as a practical concern when programming in Scala, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

While the approach may be straightforward,

1. its guarantees can be broken by reflection;
2. it requires quite a bit of effort, which the Scala team may think not worth it or not a priority.